# Ensure that we initialize each variable once and only once

Tags: c++, testing, static, c++14, llvm

Below is a test from LLVM's exception handling library libcxxabi (which by the way uses LLVM's stack unwind library libunwind):

```
// libcxxabi\test\test_guard.pass.cpp
...
// Ensure that we initialize each variable once and only once.
namespace test1 {
    static int run_count = 0;
    int increment() {
        ++run_count;
        return 0;
    }
    void helper() {
        static int a = increment();
        ((void)a);
    }
    void test() {
        static int a = increment(); ((void)a);
        assert(run_count == 1);
        static int b = increment(); ((void)b);
        assert(run_count == 2);
        helper();
        assert(run_count == 3);
        helper();
        assert(run_count == 3);
    }
}

...

int main()
{
    test1::test();
}
```

Maybe I'm missing something obvious but I'm not sure what's the idea behind this test (what does it test and how). Do you have any ideas?

Why are these three variables

```
static int run_count
static int a (in test(), not in helper())
static int b
```

declared to be static?

Comment: It tests whether `static`s work the way they're supposed to work.

Comment: Could you please explain it in a little bit more detail?

Comment: Answering the question in the title: How about something like [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) or the related [`std::once_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/once_flag)?

Comment: Imagine `static` initializes variables more than once. Stare at the asserts and see what happens.

Comment: @PasserBy How can this happen? In this program there's no possibility for any static variable to be initialized more that once even if we remove static.

Comment: @embedc Yes there is; remove `static` in `helper`.

Comment: @molbdnilo OK, Got it. But what about the other three static (static int run_count, static int a, static int b)? Why are these variables static also?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I've removed static from run_count and it counts perfectly

Comment: Indeed, the static for `run_count` is just the C `static`, to limit the scope tot he translation unit. Read too fast, thought it was inside the function.

Comment: Most certainly this test just ensures that the compiler does no mess around when optimizations are on. Maybe an e.g. wrong `prvalue` optimization would do something problematic here.

Comment: Would `language-laywer` be an appropriate tag to add?

Answer (score 1):

It's a test to ensure that the compiler works correctly. It should pass on any confirming c++ compiler.

I'd guess it's there as a quick sanity check, there will be more in-depth tests which might be harder to understand why by they are failing on a buggy compiler.

The variables are declared static to ensure the various forms of static variables are initialised correctly and that the initialisers are only called once.

Comment: I've updated my question to make it more specific. Could you please take a look at it?